# Bootstrap navbar responsive issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me out in laying out the basic bootstrap grid system. I have been trying to make, but its not working.

Can anyone help me in laying out the basic-structure alone for this navbar above on how about going with cols and rows with some pseudo text alone.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have inbetween

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">/*HERE*/</div>
```

will collapse as intended.

I can recommend you 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar
and
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Yours

Answer (score 0):

Learn about bootstrap's grid system and try using columns.

you're not using

```
<div class='col-lg-5'>content</div>
```

ect..

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid